# Safari on iOS always prompt for a client certificate

Tags: ios, azure, ssl, safari, certificate

I've got an ASP.NET MVC application deployed on Azure, and users login using a client certificate.
All the process works fine on desktop browser (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE) and Android, but on iOS Safari asks to the user to select the proper client certificate at **every link** tapped if there're more than one certificate available installed. I've got the same issue on MacOS's Safari.

I install certificates (.pfx) through the iOS Mail app.

I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/343231/how-do-i-make-safari-automatically-use-a-particular-client-certificate-for-an-en) that probably this is issue is due to iCloud keychain manager and I have to change the identity property of the certificate to accept all application's url (something like https://example.com/*), but seem it doesn't work.

Is there a way to select the certificate just one time as I do on other clients?